# if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') === TRUE) doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

`if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') === TRUE)` doesn't work.

What I am trying to is achieve that when on the homepage e.g. http://www.amazon.co.uk/ that it will trigger what is inside the statement.

This may be complicated by the fact this is a redirect from another page

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); = /string(1) 
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; = "/"

php version 5.4

Thank you for your help, I have fixed my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't `strlen('foo') === 'pony'` work?](http://php.net/strpos)

Comment: One small advice: You do NOT have to check '=== TRUE'. Just write it like this: if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')){}

Comment: ^ and then when the position of string is 0 you will not get it because PHP will cast it to FALSE.

Comment: @teckygamer If one answer has been helpful to you, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green bordered tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

That is because, like the docs tell you, [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) never returns true.

It either returns a positive integer (found) or boolean false (not found).

So check for `!== false`.

Answer (score 1):

The `strpos()` function, returns a numeric value representing the position of the second string in the first string. Hence it will never be equal to TRUE.

strpos() can return FALSE if the string isn't found, hence you should be writing

```
if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`strpos()` from manual:

> strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a
>   string

So you are checking if the return is TRUE, and it never is. You need to check it with !== FALSE. Why? Because === checks for the value AND the type of variable. When you do == it will check only for value, and when value is 0 PHP will cast it to FALSE, since PHP is loosely typed.